# Bitnami Mediawiki set default page

Tags: php, apache, mediawiki, lamp, bitnami

I'm running a virtual machine for Mediawiki packaged by Bitnami (https://bitnami.com/redirect/to/2307584/bitnami-mediawiki-1.39.3-r2-debian-11-amd64.ova) and I've set a domain name for the machine so that now the wiki responds to say mydomain.com.

Whenever accessing mydomain.com I get redirected to the wiki, but I don't want to.

When visiting mydomain.com I want an index page to be displayed, while I want to be redirected to the wiki whenever accessing URLS starting by mydomain.com/wiki.

Of course, I've already (and unsuccessfully) tried with [what's suggested in the docs](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/mediawiki/administration/publish-pages/):

> If you already have a Web page and you want to serve its content with Apache, copy your file to the default document root directory at /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/.

What am I missing?

Edit:
I've also tried to restore the original LocalSettings.php file but, even in this case, I cannot access the default index.html in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs

**Edit 2**: The problem is rooted in `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf`, towards the end, it contains the following lines:

```
IncludeOptional "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/*.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf"
```

Both `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/mediawiki-vhost.conf` and `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` define a virtual host listening on port 80 (the second being thus ignored) and referring to two different `DocumentRoot` paths.

Placing my index.html file in the `DocumentRoot` defined in `mediawiki-vhost.conf` would solve the problem, but this approach is neither clean nor extensible. Any hints?

Comment: What do you want the index page to look like?

Comment: You should probably read this page:
https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/mediawiki/get-started/understand-config/
And then edit the apache config to suit your needs

Comment: Let's keep things simple: for the moment a simple HTML page saying "hello" is fine.
I've been browsing all around the official docs, but I'm not familiar with Apache so I still don't understand where to start from.

Comment: I guess when your file is called "index.html" and you placed it in `/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/`, and then you go to mydomain.com/index.html, it shows you the file. Is this guess correct?

Comment: no, that's the point: not even restoring the original LocalSettings.php in /bitnami/mediawiki/